# Elasticsearch error "Number of documents in the index can't exceed [2147483519]"

Tags: elasticsearch

Using elasticsearch 7.10 I'm trying to run a delete-by-query to delete many records.

However my log is showing thsis error and no records get deleted. The task then ends without doing anything.

```
[INFO ][o.e.t.LoggingTaskListener] [elk1] 1167 finished with response BulkByScrollResponse[took=1.6m,timed_out=false,sliceId=null,updated=0,created=0,deleted=0,batches=1,versionConflicts=0,noops=0,retries=0,throttledUntil=0s,bulk_failures=[{"index":"logdata","type":"_doc","id":"K2FA74wBj1cuLcKb136J","cause":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Number of documents in the index can't exceed [2147483519]"},"status":400}, {"index":"logdata","type":"_doc","id":"L2FA74wBj1cuLcKb136N","cause":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Number of documents in the index can't exceed [2147483519]"},"status":400}, {"index":"logdata","type":"_doc","id":"MGFA74wBj1cuLcKb136R","cause":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Number of documents in the index can't exceed [2147483519]"},"status":400}],search_failures=[]]
```

These used to delete without any problem, I'm not sure if a setting was changed somewhere. How can I remove this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this documentation. There is a similar issue:

[elasticsearch.co](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-throwing-number-of-documents-in-the-index-cannot-exceed-2147483519/242512).

I would try to split the index then delete it.

[split index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-split-index.html)